# Finance app for personal and business

Tags: software-recommendation, ipad

I am trying to find an iPad app which I can use to keep track of my personal and business finances. I am currently both employed by a company and self-employed working on my own projects in my spare time which make a little money. It's a hobby business really but turns over enough money to warrant keeping track of.

I would like to be able to have one section for business where I put income and expenses for that and then a separate personal bit where I can put the income from my business as well as the income from my 'real' job and then be able to make note of my own personal spending and bills.

So far I've only been able to find 2 separate apps.

**Edit**
Must be able to work in the UK!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure it would be as good as you need for business finance but you should give a try to [Mint.com](https://www.mint.com/).

Comment: Thanks I was looking at that one. From the reviews it appears that you have to enter your bank details and it gives you a break down of your account, however their security isn't up to scratch and it got hacked and lost a lot of details.

Comment: +1 for Mint. It's a great service that's helped me wrangle my unruly financial management skills under control. I've been using it for two years now, and have yet to have any personal data (that I know of) leaked to the public. In contrast, I've had my PII (Personally Identifiable Information) potentially stolen from my employer (US Navy) several times in the past year.

Comment: It appears to be US and Canada only. I'll update my question to note I'm in the UK.

Comment: Maybe you can find this post interesting: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1190/is-there-a-good-equivalent-to-mint-com-for-users-outside-the-usa